# Swift UI and shadow colors

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

So, I need a button in iOS / swift, that has outer shadow on bottom and right border, and inner shadow on top and left border. I was studying tutorials for several days, and came up with following solution that is ALMOST what I need.

```
internal func Setup() {
        self.backgroundColor = .white

        self.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left:30, bottom: 10,  right: 30)

        // Outer shadow 
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 6
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2

        // call to add inner shadow
        self.addInnerShadow()

    }

    internal func addInnerShadow() {
        let cornerRadius = self.bounds.height / 2

        let innerShadow = CALayer()
        innerShadow.frame = bounds
        // Shadow path (1pt ring around bounds)
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: innerShadow.bounds.insetBy(dx: -1, dy: -1), cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
        let cutout = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: innerShadow.bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).reversing()
        path.append(cutout)

        innerShadow.shadowPath = path.cgPath
        innerShadow.masksToBounds = true

        // Shadow properties. Color is SAME as in outer shadow, but will come out differently
        innerShadow.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
        innerShadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 8, height: 8)
        innerShadow.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        innerShadow.shadowRadius = 6
        innerShadow.cornerRadius = cornerRadius


        // Add
        layer.addSublayer(innerShadow)
    }
```

Function Setup() is called during button's init(), and it all creates nice shadowed button with rounded corners.

[image]

But the question is - why the top inner shadow is so light? It should be of the same color as the bottom outer shadow. If I set any other color (like red), it is always very light, with only a tint of the required color. Why? Is it possible to control the color of inner shadow as directly as I do it with outer shadow?

Comment: innerShadow.masksToBounds = true this is the reason sir

Comment: let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: innerShadow.bounds.insetBy(dx: -5, dy: -5), cornerRadius: cornerRadius)` use this line to get more visible shadow

Comment: @jawadAli It is not. If I remove masksToBounds, shadow spreads outside the area of rounded rect. If I inset it by -5, shadow is (logically) more saturated at edges. But in both variants the color is still gray and not black.